# Need to replace objects with matching ID in array using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm saving form data with this PHP file, and it appends the data fine each time I submit the form. I just need a way to overwrite specific objects in the array based on the ID in the ID field of the form.

For example, I'd like to change the **attributeType** value in the form for ID 147 to a different value, submit, and have it only overwrite the first object (rather than appending another object with ID 147).

I've tried to use the array_splice() method but haven't had success.

Process.php

```html
<?php
    
   $myFile = "data/data.json";
   $arr_data = array(); // create empty array

  try
  {
    //Get form data
    $formdata = array(
       'ID'=> $_POST['ID'],
       'attributeName'=> $_POST['attributeName'],
       'valueX'=> $_POST['valueX'],
       'valueY'=> $_POST['valueY'],
       'valueHeight'=>$_POST['valueHeight'],
       'valueWidth'=> $_POST['valueWidth'],
       'valueURL'=> $_POST['valueURL'],
       'attributeType'=> $_POST['attributeType']
    );

    //Get data from existing json file
    $jsondata = file_get_contents($myFile);

    // converts json data into array
    $arr_data = json_decode($jsondata, true);

    // Push user data to array
    array_push($arr_data,$formdata);

    //Convert updated array to JSON
    $jsondata = json_encode($arr_data);
    
    //write json data into data.json file
    if(file_put_contents($myFile, $jsondata)) {
         echo 'Data successfully saved';
     }
    else 
         echo "error";

   }
   catch (Exception $e) {
            echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
   }

?>
```

data.json

```js
[{"ID":"147","attributeName":"PatientName","valueX":"50","valueY":"50","valueHeight":"50","valueWidth":"50","valueURL":"www.test.com","attributeType":"incomplete"},{"ID":"148","attributeName":"Complaints","valueX":"50","valueY":"50","valueHeight":"50","valueWidth":"50","valueURL":"www.test.com","attributeType":"missing"}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to loop through the existing dataset, check to see if the ID already exists, if it does, make note of the index and update the record. If the ID does not exist, append the array.

(This solution updates the *entire* record if the ID is the same)

```
<?php

$json = '[{"ID":"147","attributeName":"PatientName","valueX":"50","valueY":"50","valueHeight":"50","valueWidth":"50","valueURL":"www.test.com","attributeType":"incomplete"},{"ID":"148","attributeName":"Complaints","valueX":"50","valueY":"50","valueHeight":"50","valueWidth":"50","valueURL":"www.test.com","attributeType":"missing"}]';

$formdata = array(
  'ID'=> 147,
  'attributeName'=> 'PatientName',
  'valueX'=> 55,
  'valueY'=> 60,
  'valueHeight'=> 55,
  'valueWidth'=> 60,
  'valueURL'=> 'www.test.com',
  'attributeType'=> 'incomplete'
);

$arr = json_decode($json, true);

$updateKey = null;

foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
    if ($v['ID'] == $formdata['ID']) {
        $updateKey = $k;
    }
}

if ($updateKey === null) {
    array_push($arr_data,$formdata);
} else {
    $arr[$updateKey] = $formdata;
}
```